# Travel to USA with visa in expiring passport

Tags: visas, usa, egyptian-citizens, passport-renewals

I am Egyptian but living in Taiwan. I am travelling to USA for two weeks only and returning back to Taiwan. I am using two passports: Passport 1 has less than six months left to expiry but contains the valid USA visa, Passport 2 is a new one.

Does it pose any problem for me?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming both passports are from the same country, that should be no problem. Visa have an expiration date that's not tied to the expiration date of the passport they are in. I have frequently used visas in expired passports with a matching current passports (B Visa for the US Case)